# Python Script requesting a php post request

Tags: python

Not sure if I am using the correct wording, however I am trying to run a python script on my local machine that sends a request to a form in php I am fairly new to python

When I run the python script I get no errors, like I said I am fairly new to python, what I am trying to do is insert some users into a table using a python script

I am loading the usernames from a json file and iterate through them, I suspect the problem to be the URL I run the request against and I am unsure as to how this should be specified when running a request to a local server. The server is apache

```
import requests
import os
import random
import string
import json

chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()'
random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))

url = 'http://localhost/../../index.php'

names = json.loads(open('names1.json').read())

for name in names:
    name_extra = ''.join(random.choice(string.digits))

    username = name.lower() + name_extra + '@yahoo.com'
    password = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(8))

    requests.post(url, allow_redirects=False, data={
        'username': username,
        'password': password
    })

    print ("sending username", username, "& password", password)
```

I get no errors the python script runs like intended, so I am suspecting it to be the URL or something I don't know about python as I literally just started

Comment: Why are the `..` in your URL?

Comment: remove `../../` from the url for sure

Comment: Since you're asking about your python code, I removed the PHP tag. What language the API you're trying to post to is made in is irrelevant.

Comment: Check the return value of `requests.post()`, or you will never learn what error message the server is sending back to you ;-)